# jQuery bxSlider "unexpected token" error

Tags: jquery, syntax-error, bxslider

Hello everyone,

I am using jQuery bxSlider. My code is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
    {
        jQuery('.abc').bxSlider(function()
            {
                mode: 'fade',
                captions: true;
            });         
    });
```

But it throws following error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Can anyone help me?
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: remove semicolon in caption: true;

Comment: Yes.. thank you @Akki619 . you are right. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an object. And they don't have `;`s.

```
captions: true;
//------------^
```

Remove the `;` and the way you are initializing is also wrong. Make it look like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.abc').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
      captions: true
  });         
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me.. How to start from a new slide in slider when page reloads??

Comment: @ved You can do using the same code above to reinitialize the slider again.